# Dropdown menu in a dropdown menu swift

Tags: swift, dropdown

So I have created a `dropdown` menu in Swift. When I press a button a `dropdown menu` appears, but my problem is that I don't know how to add another `dropdown menu` for my options from my first `dropdown`.

this is my current code for my `dropdown`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var skolButtons: [UIButton]! // buttons for different schools

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func handleSelection(_ sender: UIButton) {
        skolButtons.forEach { (button) in
            button.isHidden = !button.isHidden // Hides button and = ! is the oppesite
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


        }



    }

    @IBAction func itgTap(_ sender: UIButton) { // what happens when you tap different schools

    }
}
```

So if anyone knows how to create a sub dropdown please help me!

Comment: This isn't enough code to help you, considering we have no idea how you set up the drop down menu to begin with.

Comment: The dropdown is made with Stack View so nothing fancy